# Report non tested python file in coverage

Tags: python, code-coverage, coverage.py, pytest-cov

I am writting the test cases for an existing project and there are multiple python files to be tested, I would like to know the coverage report for all the files under project directory even though there is no testcases wrritten for this file. When I run the below command

`pytest --cache-clear --cov-report term-missing --cov=services/ tests/`

Report only shows the file which has the test cases under tests/ directory but not showing the other yet to tested files.

I have tried with the below command as well `coverage run --source=. -m pytest tests/ && coverage report -m`

Can anyone please help how it is possible ?

Comment: Can you share your directory layout? The only thing i can think is that you don't have `__init__.py` files in your directories.  Coverage.py --source=. should find all the importable files, and it uses the presence of `__init__.py` to help decide that.